# How to delay megamenu instantly appearing on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I'm trying to prevent the instant triggering of a large megamenu on a site i'm developing, which is quite annoying to the user when they mouseover the main menu without necessarily wanted to trigger the megamenu. So ideally there would be a half second delay or so to make sure the megamenu is triggered only when the user focuses long enough on the parent menu item, then no delay at all when mouse-out of the megamenu.

Basic markup example would be as below:

```
<li class="parent">
<a href="#">Foo</a>
<div class="megamenu-block">
<....content >
</div>
</li>

div.megamenu-block {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    @include opacity(0);
}

li {
    &:hover div.megamenu-block {
        z-index: 1000;
        @include opacity(1);
        pointer-events: all;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check if the mouse is still within the parent triggering element after a set period of time.  Then display the mega menu if it is.

```
$('#megaMenuHover').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Current: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y);
    if(mousePos.x >= position.left && mousePos.x < maxX && mousePos.y > position.top && mousePos.y < maxY) {
      $('.megamenu-block').addClass('open');
      console.log('still hovering');
    }
    else {
      //do nothing as element is not still hovered
    }
  }, 250);
});
```

Rest of the relevant code and working example in the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khuras0j/9/)

Alternatively, you could use the hoverIntent plugin for jQuery found [here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)